# How to reload the page using php, I am not to use anyother lan. header not working for me

Tags: php, mysql

Let me explain what i need to do, the img below is my page. it is connected to mysql on CentOs sever, also php is on centos.

- There is  Which is restore and also Delete.
- All it suppose to do is to update a value on the database.
- When its updated its either changes to restore or delete.
- I did all that my problem is that i cant see it change right when i click it, i have to reload the page.
- Like for example if I click Delete (using get) it updates the database and it should change itself to Restore, i have a php code to make it change but i have to manully refresh the page.
- I have tried php Header, it works on Xampp but not here some reason.

.

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "0.001";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page")
```

Also

```
header("Location: view.php");
```

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <?php
include "library2.php";
include "delete.php";
printHeader(); // prints the logo
?>
  <title>
    View
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="add.php">
          Add
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="view.php">
          View
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </head>

  <body>
<?php
$link = connectMysql();
$sql_query = "SELECT * from inventory;";
$result = runQuery($link, $sql_query);      

if($_GET){
deleteRestoreItem($_GET['DeleteRestore']);

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "0.001";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
}
?>
    <div id ="view">
    </br>
  </br>
</br>
<table >

  <th>
    ID
  </th>
  <th>
    Item Name
  </th>
  <th>
    Description
  </th>
  <th>
    Supplier Code
  </th>
  <th>
    Cost
  </th>
  <th>
    Selling Price
  </th>
  <th>
    Number On Hand
  </th>
  <th>
    Reorder Point
  </th>
  <th>
    Back Order
  </th>
  <th>
    Delete/Restore
  </th>
  <?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['id']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['itemName']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['description']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['supplierCode']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['cost']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['price']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['onHand']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['reorderPoint']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php print $row['backOrder']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php 
if($row['deleted']=="n")
{ 
?>
<a href="view.php?DeleteRestore=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a>

   <?php    
    }


    if($row['deleted']=="y")
      {

   ?>
      <a href="view.php?DeleteRestore=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></a><?php
      }
?>
 </td>
 </tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
</br>

</div>
 </body>
  <footer>
     <?php
         printFooter()
     ?>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * from inventory;";
$result = runQuery($link, $sql_query);
```

after

```
deleteRestoreItem($_GET['DeleteRestore']);
```

at the moment, you are first asking the database to get the content, storing it into $result, then you alter the database, then you show the first results of the state of the database before altering it. (so no changes are showed).

Change this order and it should work. First alter the DB, then ask for DB contents and show it. No refresh is needed anymore

---

**So as conclusion:**

```
<?php
$link = connectMysql();
$sql_query = "SELECT * from inventory;";
$result = runQuery($link, $sql_query);      

if($_GET){
 deleteRestoreItem($_GET['DeleteRestore']);

 $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 $sec = "0.001";
 header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
}
?>
```

should be more something like

```
<?php
$link = connectMysql();

if($_GET){
 deleteRestoreItem($_GET['DeleteRestore']);
}

$sql_query = "SELECT * from inventory;";
$result = runQuery($link, $sql_query);      

?>
```

Comment: No refresh is needed afterwards, as you can alter the DB before you shows the contents.

Comment: I am sorry, i am having trouble understanding. Can you please explain it

Comment: Please approve this answer as it fixed your problem. It's all about the logic. I've updated my answer more as the refresh is not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use ajax for that?

Or just first update states in DB, and then select all records. Then you will not need to reload your page.

Comment: i am not allowed to, and i didnt learn that language yet
(php class)